# View template solve error in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have PostController using Spring MVC to manage all posts and render all templates under folder `admin/posts/`. For example `admin/posts/new.jade`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new")
public String newPost(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("postForm", new PostForm());
    return "admin/posts/new";
}
```

Returning `admin/posts/new` will cause an error and the template `new.jade` cannot be found.  So I'm using `return admin/posts_new` instead and it' ok.

However I wanna use `return admin/posts/new` to keep templates separated. 
Can anyone help me fix it?

Here is the templates structure. `webapp/views` is my templates root directory.

```
webapp
|   ├── views
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── home
│   │   ├── index.jade
│   │   ├── layout
│   │   │   ├── admin.jade
│   │   │   ├── footer.jade
│   │   │   ├── head.jade
│   │   │   └── navbar.jade
│   │   ├── posts
│   │   │   └── new.jade
│   │   ├── posts_edit.jade
│   │   ├── posts_index.jade
│   │   ├── posts_new.jade
│   │   └── settings.jade
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── about.jade
│   │   └── index.jade
│   ├── layout
│   │   ├── app.jade
│   │   ├── footer.jade
│   │   ├── head.jade
│   │   ├── navbar.jade
│   │   └── top.jade
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── archive.jade
│   │   ├── index.jade
│   │   └── show.jade
│   └── users
│       └── signin.jade
```

Comment: What is webapp? The maven directory? How is your view resolver configured? Also your `admin/posts/new` isn't under views...

Comment: You can see my project structure [https://github.com/Raysmond/SpringBlog](https://github.com/Raysmond/SpringBlog) and I'm using [JadeViewResolver](https://github.com/neuland/spring-jade4j/blob/master/src/main/java/de/neuland/jade4j/spring/view/JadeViewResolver.java) provided by spring-jade4j.

Comment: Please add the information to your question, don't let people willing to help you search the internet for information.